# How to link a new dataset to an existing dataset?

Tags: geospatial, government, releasing-data, linked-data

I have to construct a dataset of hospitals.
For each hospital, I will indicate the the town/region in which it is located.

I already have dataset of towns/regions of the concerned geographic area.

In order to not repeat informations about towns/region in my new hospital dataset, I wonder if is it possible to be linked to my existing towns/regions dataset.

Many Thanks.

Comment: [Linked Data](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_data) is an approach designed specially to solve this issue. [Linked CSV](http://jenit.github.io/linked-csv/) is a set of conventions for CSV files that enable them to be linked together. I can't understand how your question is related to data.gov, probably these approaches is inapplicable in your case.

Comment: Thanks @StanislavKralin. Please, I want to know why Linked Data is not applicable is not applicable in my case ?

Comment: It sounds like it could be useful to make your data suitable for putting into GIS by giving each hospital co-ordinate data (perhaps it already comes with geographic location?)

Comment: Yes, each hospital has co-ordinate data. But the administrative location (town/department) is as important as co-ordinate. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

First model the relationships from the geographic area and probably expand it more:

```
Dallas > located_in > Texas
Dallas > country > USA
Dallas > located_in > USA

Texas > first_level_administrative_division_of > USA
Texas > located_in > USA
```

Then do the same for the hospitals list, and merge those that match completely.

You can also create a fake identifier of the kind USA/Texas/Dallas and again merge on that criteria. The tree can be as deep as you want.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks @marfi. Please, I want to know if the data.gov of countries are constructed in a linked way ?

Comment: data.gov is a portal, what file in particular you are working with?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't know that "data.gov" was the US open data portal. By data.gov I meant to say a generic open data of a country.

Comment: It is not getting any clearer. You have to give a specific example. In Europe we use LAU and NUTS in US you use FIPS, it is not one standard.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you assign a ID to each relevant geographic combination in your address database:

> ID; Town; State; Country
>
> 1 ; Miami; Florida; USA

after you did than you could add a column to your hospital list (like "geo_id") and assign the correct geo_id to each hospital.

> hospital name ;[...]; geo id

as a result the geo_id would link to the correct information on the other table.

If you have to join both tables you can do that by "hospital.geo_id = address.id"

Comment: Ok, your idea is the basic of relational databases. But I want do this in Linked Data manner. The difference is that in the later, this contribute to the web of data.